# Error: Create a Visualforce page to use as a custom action

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, quickaction

thank you for your reply.

I need to create Quick Action - generate PDF on opportunity object.
i have PDF visualforce page and custom controller.
If i want to add my vf page in Quick action i get error:

[image]

As I understand it, in order for the page to be displayed in this field I need a standard controller, but I have a custom controller.
How could I fix this error? Maybe I need to change my controller? Or other what can i do...

My VF Pages look like:

[image]

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Custom Controller and you still need to use the standard controller functions you can use a [Controller Extension.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm)

Change your Header to like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="controllerTest">
```

You would also need to modify your controller to handle the Opportunity. Like this:

```
private final Opportunity oppt;

// The extension constructor initializes the private member
// variable oppt by using the getRecord method from the standard
// controller.
public controllerTest(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.oppt = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
}
```

This gives you the best of both worlds. Allows you to use the standard controller while still being able to write custom methods if needed.

Comment: thats work, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order, to make VF page available, to select as `Opportunity` `new` action, your apex page should have property `standardController="Opportunity"` e.g.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
...
```